# Remove files recursively in Linux

Tags: linux, ubuntu, fedora

How to remove all the .pyc files recursively from a certain directory including sub-directories?
I tried

```
$rm -f *.pyc
```

This seems to work for only the current directory, but not the directories following it.
Please help me..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
cd <your_directory>
find . -name "*.pyc" -exec rm -rf {} \;
```

This will remove all the *.pyc files from your current directory and its sub directory

Comment: I felt that this is a very simple command.. self explanatory..

Comment: Why doesn't anyone think of using `rm -rf *.pyc` ?

Comment: @NehalJ.Wani because that wouldn't work. `rm` does not have a search functionailty. the `rm -rf` can delete directories (and subdirectories recursively). But not search through subdirectories and delete only files.

Answer (score 5):

Use `find`:

```
find /some/directory -type f - name "*.pyc" -exec rm -f {} \;
```

or, if your `find` has the `-delete` option:

```
find /some/directory -type f - name "*.pyc" -delete
```

Answer (score 2):

```
find /var/www/html -name "*.pyc" -delete
```

Comment: You need to quote *.pyc otherwise the shell will expand it. This will not work if there are pyc files in the base directory.